# Apple Script for System Events (UI reading) very slow

Tags: performance, applescript

I've written an Apple Script for checking a UI Element (table) of a specific application (Avid Pro Tools). The table consists of a given number of rows. Each row has an attribute for selected (boolean) and index (integer). The script is returning a list of the index number of every row which has the attribute "selected" to true. The script is working, however, it is incredibly slow. It will take a few seconds to return the values. Is there any way to speed this up?

tell application "System Events"

```
return value of attribute "AXIndex" of (rows whose value of attribute "AXSelected" is true) of table "Track List" of (windows whose name contains "Mix: ") of application process "Pro Tools" of application "System Events"
```

end tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an extended comment than a bone fide answer, but here is what would I would consider in a similar situation:

- What are you doing with the `AXIndex` values later on in the script, i.e. do you need the index numbers to the rows, or can you just store the references to the `row` objects ?  Retrieving a list of index values suggests you'll be iterating through those values at some point, so I wonder if you're slowing your script down by accessing an `attribute` you may not need, then iterating through a list you could incorporate into the filter.
- If there's an `attribute` named `"AXSelected"`, there's a good chance there's a `property` named `selected`, which usually contains the same value and would be faster to retrieve:

  ```
  ... of (rows whose selected = true) of ...
  ```
- Is the script *actually* being slow, or is it just having to perform a demanding set of complex operations ?  There are two `whose` filters and one of these is performing a `contains` comparison (you can think of this as asking it to iterate through characters in a string to find a matching subset, versus an equality test that would on require a glance to know when something doesn't match).  See what happens when you *don't* filter the `windows` list ?  If the purpose of the filter is to isolate windows that have a `table "Track List"` element, you might not need to: if you're unlucky, removing the filter would create an error for the first `window` where *System Events* can't find that particular `table` (and hence the attributes you're retrieving); but quite often, it just inserts some `missing value` items in your final result that would be a small trade-off for a big increase in speed.
- Finally, your actual construction of the compound filters is syntactically flawed, and I'm surprised it actually runs and returns meaningful results.  The sub-clause that reads:

  ```
  (rows whose value of attribute "AXSelected" is true) of table "Track List"
  ```

  doesn't actually make sense, because there's no indication at the point where you define the filter what `rows` is and what other element they belong to.  It's seems obvious that you've stated they belong to the `table` object, but the statement actually references some objects of class `row` that could exist anywhere, and the ones that are selected are the ones that belong to `table "Track List"`.  As an analogy, it's sort of like a *split infinitive*, that the English language has somehow acclimatised to accepting these as syntax forms that make sense because we assume the underlying meaning  without much difficulty, but they are logically corrupt and in some other languages would result in a person not being able to understand what is being said, or assume an incorrect meaning.

  So I wonder if AppleScript might be doing that, and if so, is AppleScript making incorrect assumptions and returning inaccurate results; or is AppleScript making correct assumptions, but being slowed down in order to untangle the syntax ?

  Here's the correct form of the expression, including removal of the superfluous double-referencing of `application "System Events"`:

  ```
  tell application "System Events" to return ¬
      the value of attribute "AXIndex" of ¬
          (rows of table "Track List" of ¬
              (windows of application process "Pro Tools" whose name contains "Mix:") ¬
                  whose value of attribute "AXSelected" is true)
  ```

  Hopefully, the way I've split the clauses over multiple lines helps to illustrate more clearly why this makes syntactical sense in a way the original does not.  It's also when I noticed the same ambiguous referencing occur with the `windows` filter clause.

---

#### Conclusion

I can't promise any of these suggestions will result in quicker execution times. This is more of a walk-through the thought processes that help me improve my scripts, by considering all the *"what ifs?"* and asking the seemingly-pointless questions every time to myself.

Feel free to provide a bit more context and insight into what the rest of your script is doing overall, and perhaps it'll reveal a different way to get the same result at the end but in less time.

Comment: Thanks CJK and sorry for my late reply. You pointed me to right direction! AXIndex is in fact not necessary. I'm now iterating through the list with a repeat loop instead of reading the AXIndex attribute and that's A LOT quicker (100ms versus a few seconds on a list with 150 rows). As you suggested I moved from the attribute "AXSelected" to the property "selected", but I don't know if that's quicker than before. Finally, I changed the expression for the windows filter as you suggested. The filter is important for the script but that wasn't the bottleneck anyway (take a few ms). Many thanks!!