# Applescript is very slow to get a simple button which is part of a big group

Tags: applescript

here is a applescript code for Pro Tools.. I try to select a button to open a windows. the button is in a group. (there is hundred of groups, so hundreds of button)
Some part of my code are very slow. Like setting a button ?? or getting a button value..
I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong ?

Here is my all code, but the line
`set V's outputButton to button  "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group groupTitle of V's editWindow`

after `log "test 2"` seems already too slow for me

```
# in this script, I want to automatically set pan of a stereo track to -80 80..
# the pan interface is a dolby 5.1
# This is a first step, the goal at the end would be to set automatically to predefined value the pan for stereo - dolby - atmo..
# But this is too slow (considering working on a movie having at least 500 tracks..)


 
script V
    property automationMenuItem : missing value
    property editWindow : missing value
    property trackListTable : missing value
    property selectedRow : missing value
    property trackName : missing value
    property outputButton : missing value
    property outputValue : missing value
    property previewButton : missing value
    property allWindows : missing value
    property currentWindow : missing value
    property automationWindow : missing value
    property panWindow : missing value
    property frontPan : missing value
    property test : missing value
end script


tell application "finder"
    tell application "System Events"
        set  PT to the first application process whose creator type is "PTul"
        tell  PT
            activate
            set boolAutomationOpen to true
            set frontmost to true
            -- open automation windows if not open
            set V's automationMenuItem to menu item "Automation" of menu "Window" of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
            set status to value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of V's automationMenuItem
            if status is not equal to "✓" then
                set boolAutomationOpen to false
                click V's automationMenuItem
                delay 0.2
            end if
            log "test0"
            -- find edit windows
            set V's editWindow to first window whose name starts with "edit:"
            -- set V's trackListTable to first table of V's editWindow whose description is "Track List"
            -- set V's selectedRow to first row of V's trackListTable whose selected = true
            -- set selectedIndex to value of attribute "AXIndex" of selectedRow

            set V's trackName to "VI ST"
            log "test1"
            -- set V's trackName to name of button 1 of UI element 1 of V's selectedRow
            -- -- function to replace in string (grrr)
            -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Shown. "
            -- set theTextItems to every text item of V's trackName
            -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
            -- set V's trackName to theTextItems as string
            -- set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
            
            set groupTitle to V's trackName & " - Audio Track "
            log "test2" -- slow


            set V's outputButton to button  "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group groupTitle of V's editWindow

            log "test25" -- slow

            set V's outputValue to value of V's outputButton

            log "test3" -- slow

            if V's outputValue is not equal to "open" then
                perform action "AXPress" of V's outputButton
            end if


            log "test4" -- very slow !! see click click or end event

            -- Search within windows 
            set V's allWindows to every window of PT
            set V's test to first window of PT whose button whose title is ""

            -- log V's testÒ

            repeat with  currentWindow in V's allWindows

                if (count (buttons of  currentWindow whose title contains "Suspend Automation")) is greater than 0 then
                    -- Click and exit the script.
                    set V's automationWindow to  currentWindow
                end if

                if (count (buttons of currentWindow whose title contains "Automation Safe")) is greater than 0 then
                    -- Click and exit the script.
                    set V's panWindow to  currentWindow
                end if

            end repeat

            log "test5"

            set V's previewButton to button "Enable Auto Preview Mode" of V's automationWindow

            if value of attribute "AXvalue" of V's previewButton is not equal to "selected" then
                click V's previewButton
            end if



            log "test6" 
                
            set V's frontPan to text field "Front Pan Numerical" of V's panWindow
            set test to value of attribute "AXValue" of V's frontPan 
            perform action "AXPress" of V's frontPan
            keystroke "-80"
            key code 76

            log "test7"

            set FRPan to text field "F/R Pan Numerical" of V's panWindow
            perform action "AXPress" of FRPan
            keystroke "100"
            key code 76

            log "test8"

            set CenterPan to text field "Front Center % Numerical" of V's panWindow
            perform action "AXPress" of CenterPan
            key code 48
            keystroke "80"
            key code 76

            perform action "AXPress" of CenterPan
            repeat 3 times
                key code 48
            end repeat
            keystroke "100"
            key code 76

            click menu item "Write to All Enabled" of menu "Automation" of menu item "Automation" of menu "Edit" of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1

            click V's previewButton
            perform action "AXPress" of V's outputButton

            if boolAutomationOpen is not true then 
                click automationMenuItem
            end if


        end tell
        --your code
    end tell
    --your code
end tell
```

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565841/apple-script-for-system-events-ui-reading-very-slow

Comment: @matt why is it similar, I do not use index here, nor any loop..  I do not see why this line ```set V's outputButton to button  "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group groupTitle of V's editWindow``` is so slow..

Comment: Hey, I didn't suggest it's a pure duplicate. But for sure, it's the same idea: using System Events to drive the Pro Tools user interface via the Accessibility APIs is slow. In effect, this is a non-scriptable app. Therefore you have to ask the Accessibility API, which is actually intended to help non-sighted people navigate the user interface, to navigate the interface for you. That is slow, and when the user interface is very involved, it gets _really_ slow. Pro Tools has a very involved user interface.

Comment: That is why Avid has finally introduced a native scripting API. https://avidtech.my.salesforce-sites.com/pkb/articles/FAQ/Pro-Tools-Scripting-SDK-FAQ If you want to script Pro Tools with any hope of reasonable speed, that's what you'll have to use.

Comment: @matt I already look at the native scripting, in fact, there is only 84 command for now..  I can create tracks,rename tracks etc.. we are very very far to be able to set pan on specific tracks..  84 command for a software complex as Pro tools, it is a joke. I guess they want people to used soundflow and pay (again!) 10$ per month. I'll try to use less the system events..  That might help, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree, the situation is far from satisfactory. I'm just putting the situation in perspective: what you are doing is, by nature and necessity, inherently slow, for reasons that I have explained; and you are not the only person to notice this. I repeat, this app is (for your purposes) not scriptable; what you're doing is a hack and a slow hack at that. If you're going to do things this way, you just have to accept that. By the way, I strongly recommend UIBrowser (and Script Debugger) for this sort of task. https://latenightsw.com/freeware/ui-browser/

Comment: I don't have Pro Tools to test on, but my instincts questions why you've put all your properties in a script object rather than leaving them as top-level properties. I don't see how that would give any advantages in this case, and it may be gumming up the works. Have you tried it with simple properties?

Comment: @ted Wrigley I'm sure I understand well the properties concept here..  I though it was a way to "kind of" work by reference and in fact it did improve the speed of my code.. thanks I'll to put at the top level (I cannot try now, I do that to help a friends and I do not have a mac at home...) do you think for some variable I should used references also ?